Не работает перенос русских слов по слогам в Opera и Edge
По состоянию на 2024 год hyphens: auto для русского языка работает в Chrome, Firefox и даже в Safari, но не работает в Opera и Edge, хотя MDN заявляет, что «Hyphenation dictionary for Russian» давно есть во всех браузерах.
Что происходит? Я должен доустановить какие-то словари вручную, или MDN просто врёт, или что-то ещё?


div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  hyphens: auto;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
<div lang="en">Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content.</div>
<div lang="ru">Широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства.</div>



Скриншот из Microsoft Edge 125.0.2535.92:

